# Editing an UITableViewCell and change textlabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i want to edit,delete and reorder the cells in an uitableview. i am good with deleting and reordering but how to edit a cell?

i want to change cell.textLabel.text when edit button is clicked.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text should change to what?I mean what should be the value of cell.textLabel.text when edit is clicked?If you just want to change simple text then you can reload table on edit click.

Comment: that textlabel should be editable so that i can change the text

Comment: You can not edit lable as it is. You have to add textfield on cell if you want to change label or editable when edit button click. Then when you tap cell it will bring keyboard because its uitextfield and you can edit existing text with new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See the answer Given by mihiros is very correct.**

I will also suggest to do this:

1. On click of a Edit Button on cell, you can remove or hide the text and replace it with textField there.
2. Add the required text in that field and then on click on Ok or done fetch the text from text field and provide it to the **cell.textLabel.text** and then UnHide the Label (if u have hidden it while editing).

**Added**: you can also put the default text in the Textfield on click of the Edit button which was written in the cell.textLabel.text.